# Find intersection of two planes with constant k?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the planes:

x - y + z = 1

kx + 2y - 2z = 7

For what value of k do the planes intersect at:

- One point
- Many points
- No points

I know if the planes are parallel (k=2) the planes never intersect but what about the other two cases?

Comment: I think you meant that at $k=-2$ they never intersect, right?

Comment: the intersection of two 2 dimensional planes in 3 dimensional space is either empty, a line or a plane (the last case happens when they coincide). It is never a point (that may be in 4 or more dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

So, at $k=-2$ the normal vectors of both planes are co-linear and since they are not the same plane, there is no intersection. In any other case, you would have many points of intersection. More specifically, you would have a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which describes the intersection of the two planes. Thinking geometrically, there is no way you can have two planes intersect in only one point in $\mathbb{R}^3$.